# Invalid block tag: 'add_preserved_filters'

Tags: django

In the admin, we're getting the above error when using the `cycle` template tag.

Full stack trace:

```
 TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/app/page/
Invalid block tag: 'add_preserved_filters', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/app/page/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'add_preserved_filters', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
Exception Location: /home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 327
Python Executable:  /home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/alex/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: are you overriding the default `change_form` ?

Comment: Well this is the change list. But I was overriding the `change_list`. When removed I get another exception. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

This template tag is available in Django >= 1.6.
According to your backtrace, you'are using Django-1.5.1.

Please compare templatetags in [admin_urls.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_urls.py) from 1.5 with those in [admin_urls.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_urls.py) from 1.6.